# Varnish - usage of non latin characters of an URL in VCL

Tags: varnish, url, charset

I have a client, which needs Varnish to be installed on his server. He is russian speaking and has an online shop with the following example URL, which needs to be excluded from cache (`корзина` is the cart page).

```
www.example.com/корзина/
```

So, is there any special way of using non latin characters in VCL, as it seems not to work for me. I tried the following (actual code is longer than that and working for other web pages, this is just to show you an example):

```
if (
! req.url ~ "(...|корзина/|...)"
# or URLencoded:
! req.url ~ "(...|%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/|...)"
)
{ unset req.http.cookie; }
```

Both seem to not work for me somehow - my rules are not triggered. So, how should I use non latin characters in VCL?

Answer (score 0):

Non latin characters in an URL must be encoded AND lower case:

```
tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" < <(php -r 'echo( urlencode("корзина") . PHP_EOL );')
```

So this will work:

```
req.url ~ "(...|%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0|...)" ...
```

This won't:

```
req.url ~ "(...|%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/|...)" ...
req.url ~ "(...|корзина/|...)" ...
```